# Untrusting parent: Storing some model attributes in a separate keystore

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I've got a `Card` model that has the following fields:

- `id`
- `name`
- `brand`
- `number`
- `exp_month`
- `exp_year`

.. that corresponds to the card details for a particular loyalty card brand. These are currently being stored to a MySQL server.

I'd like to store the `number`,`exp_month` and `exp_year` fields **separately** .. in a Redis keystore on a different server.

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :save_card_data

  private:

  def save_card_data
    # Save the card data to a Redis store
    redis = Redis.new(url: CONFIG['cardholder_keystore_url'])
    redis.hmset(self.id, "number", self.number, "exp_month", self.exp_month, 
                "exp_year", self.exp_year, "cvc", self.cvc)
  end
end
```

The above code does what I need it to do (save the card data to the Redis store), *but it also gets saved to the MySQL database*.

What options do I have to prevent it from storing it to the MySQL DB? Can I remove the fields from the MySQL DB altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom getter and setter for each field that you'd like to store on Redis, and save the details individually.